# WCF rest service 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, post

I encountered followed exception while accessing service method.All GET methods working properly on my service but when i run a POST method as followed i am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

https://mservice.domain.com/ServicesRestful.svc/json/addorder

> {"userId":"30155496","locationId":"10","order":"lorem"}

**Service Code**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "addorder", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceException), Name = "ServiceException")]
Standard AddOrder(string personId, int locationId, string order);
```

**Error message**

> The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The
>   expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can
>   be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the
>   binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more
>   details.

Comment: So, after the error message is plain english, *did you* `See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your contract in this way:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "addorder", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceException), Name = "ServiceException")]
Standard AddOrder(Order order);
```

Where your `Order` class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember]
    public string personId {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int locationId {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string order {get; set;}
}
```

Now, try and run. Make sure that your `JSON` is in proper format.